# How do enable root proxying in webpack dev server?

Tags: webpack

I have a server running on `localhost:5474` and I have a webpack dev server. I would like the webpack dev server to proxy to `localhost:5474`.

I got proxying working fine if I provide an extra part of the URL, but I don't want to do this.

Following the directions [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy), it says

> Note that requests to root won't be proxied by default. To enable root
>   proxying, the devServer.index option should be specified as a falsy
>   value:

```
devServer: {
  index: '', // specify to enable root proxying
  host: '...',
  contentBase: '...',
  proxy: {
    context: () => true,
    target: 'http://localhost:1234'
  }
}
```

I'm not really sure what the dots mean. Does that mean I put dots in there or does that mean I should provide my own values for `host` and `contentBase`?

This is my webpack config so far:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/js/app.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "js/app.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    port:3037,


    open: true,
    hot: true,

    index: '', //needed to enable root proxying

    proxy: {
      //root proxying (doesn't work yet)
      context: () => true,
      target: 'http://localhost:5474',

      //proxying with a URL value (works)
      /*
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:5474",
        pathRewrite: {"^/api" : ""}
      }*/
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  mode:'development'
};
```

But when I run the command it opens `http://localhost:3037/` and shows the listing directory.

How can I proxy `localhost:3037` to `localhost:5474` using webpack-dev-server?

Comment: did you get this working by any chance? I too want to proxy everything else beside the *.js to the backend server

Comment: Don't think so...I think I ended up realizing I like having the /proxy/ in the URL. Haven't visited it in a while though...was from a project I abandoned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible in the most recent version of webpack. As the documentation says at https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/

> Note that requests to root won't be proxied by default. To enable root proxying, the devServer.index option should be specified as a falsy value

The page gives an example of the empty string which works in my setups.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use something like this. Pay attention at `publicPath: '/public/'` it's where your bundle.js live to be able reloaded on the fly.

```
devServer: {
    index: '', //needed to enable root proxying
    port: 10001,
    publicPath: '/public/',
    proxy: {
        context: () => true,
        '/': 'http://localhost:10000'
    }
},
```